# Performance difference of 2:1 ratio between 2 near identical java methods

Tags: java, jit

My question is, from someone who understands JIT better then I, why is there such a large discrepancy (2:1 ratio) between time of execution between methods calculate2 and calculate3 where the only difference is that calculate2() sets a field with the result and calculate3() returns it.

I am interested in understanding this, as I rely a lot for very high speed processing in lots of my applications and this has large performance impact. Native code in calculate1() is still 2:1 better then best optimized JIT code in this particular case.

Here is my benchmark results:

```
CALCULATE1:: 156ms: calculated = 499,999,999,500,000,000
CALCULATE2:: 270ms: calculated = 499,999,999,500,000,000
CALCULATE3:: 411ms: calculated = 499,999,999,500,000,000
```

System info:

```
Linux tardis 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And here is the code that generated this:

```
package org.cni.examples;

import org.cni.annotation.CAccessor;

public class SumIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");

        long max = (args.length == 1 ? Long.parseLong(args[0]) : 1000000000L);

        SumIntegers worker = new SumIntegers();

        long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        worker.calculate1(max);
        long te = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("CALCULATE1:: %dms: calculated = %,d%n", (te - ts),
                worker.calculated);

        ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        worker.calculated = worker.calculate2(max);
        te = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("CALCULATE2:: %dms: calculated = %,d%n", (te - ts),
                worker.calculated);


        ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        worker.calculate3(max);
        te = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("CALCULATE3:: %dms: calculated = %,d%n", (te - ts),
                worker.calculated);
    }

    @CAccessor private long calculated;

    public native void calculate1(long max)
    /*+{
        jlong sum = 0;
        for (jlong i = 0; i < max; i ++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        // Accessor for java field: calculated  
        SumIntegers_setField_calculated(env, self_arg, sum);
    }*/;

    public long calculate2(long max) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum; // The only difference between 3
    }

    public void calculate3(long max) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        this.calculated = sum; // The only difference between 2
    }
}
```

Comment: While I don't think it is strictly applicable in this case, when creating  [micro]benchmarks, *always* ensure the result is forced/used. E.g. what happens when changing the code to: `this.calulated = calculate2(max)`? (And no, the assignment itself won't take 200ms.)

Comment: Good point, however I've been trying with dynamic field and static field, so that is why everything is from static main context. Easiest to implement both cases.

Comment: I wouldn't trust _any_ numbers from this benchmark.  What happens if you call the methods in a different order?  In a language with a JIT, you _really_ have to be using a carefully designed benchmark framework like Caliper or JMH.